# Can't connect to MySQL with JDBC connector

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have the following problem:

I can't connect to MySQL with java.

Here is the code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Date;

public class MySQLAccess {
  private Connection connect = null;
  private Statement statement = null;
  private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
  private ResultSet resultSet = null;

  public void readDataBase() throws Exception {
    try {
      // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      // Setup the connection with the DB
      connect = DriverManager
          .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?"
              + "user=root&password=");
```

It show me this problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I have Windows.. I have imported the jdbc in the PATH environmental variable, like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar
```

Is it right?

Apart from that I don't know exactly how can I write password=.... since I want it without password. Is it right like this? `password=");`

Finally, should I install something another driver too?

Thank you and sorry for the trouble but I'm new to connecting to MySQL with Java and de.mysql didn't help me so much....

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar did you add this jar into classpath?

Comment: first you could try to add the mysql connector to your projects classpath. are you using any IDE like Eclipse?

Comment: I just added it in the 'Path' environmental variable

Comment: @christian.vogel I use Netbeans.

Comment: if you are using Netbeans @Sujay already mentioned in his answer hwo to add Libs to the classpath. Have a look there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the path environment variable will not solve your problem. You need to set the "classpath" environment variable as well. One way of doing it through the command shell might be:

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar:$CLASSPATH
```

where "path" is the actual location of your driver. You can set your classpath environment variable using the System Control Panel as well.

Since, you're on Windows 7, you can also

- Right Click on "My Computer"
- Click on Properties
- Go to Advanced System Settings (On your left hand panel)
- Click on the  Advanced Tab and then the "Environment Variables"
- In the System variables, click on New and add "CLASSPATH" as the name and "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar" as the value

---

**Edit:** Since you're using NetBeans IDE to develop your application, you need to add the *mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar*  to your library. The way to do it would be to:

- Right-click on your project and click on "Properties"
- Go to "Libraries", click on "Add JAR/Folder" and add the "mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar"

Then you can go ahead and compile your code.

Comment: does this apply to windows as well?

Comment: I wrote setenv CLASSPATH C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar:$CLASSPATH but it tells me:    setenv is not recognised as an internal or external command

Comment: If u didn set the classpath then try to run with                      java -classpath mysql-connector-java-x.x.x.jar MYSQLAccess

Comment: @ApostolosKou: Which windows version do you've?

Comment: @ApostolosKou: Right Click on "My Computer" > Properties > Advanced System Settings (On your left hand panel) > Advanced Tab > "Environment Variables" > System variables >> New and add "CLASSPATH" as the name and "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar" as the value

Comment: I did as you say but it keeps telling me "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver". I use Netbeans

Comment: @ApostolosKou: Oh, you're using Netbeans. Well then the easiest way would be to add the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar` to your library. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: you mean here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0\lib, right? Should i change classpath too?

Comment: @ApostolosKou: Updated my answer. Have a look

Comment: That's it!!!!! Thanks man!! It finally worked!!! Sorry for this big trouble and thanks for you time!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
 System.out.println("MySQL Connect Example.");
 Connection conn = null;
 String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
 String dbName = "feedback";
 String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
 String userName = "root";
 String password = "";
 try {
     Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);

     System.out.println("Connected to the database");
     conn.close();
     System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

if this code not working properly. problem in your path or you did not add the jar file.

Comment: Hello it keeps telling me java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: @Apostolos do you know how to add a jar to classpath in NetBeans?